# Showing as logged in after logout (W3 Total Cache issue)

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache

I've got a login/logout link using wp_loginout(). After a user logs out their user info is still being shown by get_currentuserinfo(), only after they visit a second page does it revert to not showing any user info. They are, however actually, logged out after the initial logout (as they can't access any protected pages).

If I disable the plugin I don't experience this issue. How can I ensure that when a user logs out the change is reflected without having to visit a second page?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/

Comment: That's not an "issue", that's a "feature"! :D No, I'm not joking. You've to care about stuff like this for yourself. Btw: Is it the default login, or AJAX-powered?

Comment: It's the default login.

Comment: @SandboxWizard Have you checked `Don't cache pages for logged in users` option under page cache settings? If not, check it.

Comment: That option is checked.

Comment: Try nuking the logged in cookie in the logout page...

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters have alluded to, this is a "feature" of using cookies. Changes to cookies are only enacted on the next page refresh.

You could try adding an extra page refresh (which will make the users browser page flash) or you could add some JavaScript to destroy the cookie dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to not cache the home page and also click on the checkbox to disabled caching for login/logout pages. I encountered the same issue with my site http://www.techflict.com, It got resolved after disabling caching for home page. Hope this helps...:)